# Text edition: from Python to Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, text-editor

I have a .txt file looking like:

```
rawdata/d-0197.bmp 1 329 210 50 51
rawdata/c-0044.bmp 1 215 287 59 48
rawdata/e-0114.bmp 1 298 244 46 45
rawdata/102.bmp 1 243 126 163 143
```

I need to transform it in the following way:

-Before "rawdata", add the whole path, which is "/home/camroom/Dropbox/Internship/MyCascades/Cascade1/training/positive/".
-Add a comma after ".bmp"

-Remove the first number (so the 1).

-Put the other four numbers into square brackets [].

It would look like:

```
/home/camroom/Dropbox/Internship/MyCascades/Cascade1/training/positive/rawdata/d-0197.bmp, [329 210 50 51]
/home/camroom/Dropbox/Internship/MyCascades/Cascade1/training/positive/rawdata/c-0044.bmp, [215 287 59 48]
/home/camroom/Dropbox/Internship/MyCascades/Cascade1/training/positive/rawdata/e-0114.bmp, [298 244 46 45]
/home/camroom/Dropbox/Internship/MyCascades/Cascade1/training/positive/rawdata/102.bmp, [243 126 163 143]
```

I have done it, first by replacing "rawdata/" with nothing in a simple text editor, and then with python:

```
file=open('data.txt')
fout=open('data2.txt','w')

for line in file:
    line=line.rstrip()
    pieces=line.split('.bmp')
    pieces2=pieces[1].split()
    fout.write('/home/camroom/Dropbox/Internship/MyCascades/Cascade1/training/positive/rawdata/'+pieces[0]+'.bmp, '+'['+pieces2[1]+' '+pieces2[2]+' '+pieces2[3]+' '+pieces2[4]+']'+'\n')
fout.close()
```

But this file is going to be used in Matlab, so it would be much better to have an automatic process. How can I do the same in Matlab?

Thank you

Comment: Could you not read it in as a tab separated file as a cell array, do the manipulation and then save the cell array back to a file..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
infid  = fopen('data.txt', 'r');
outfid = fopen('data2.txt', 'w');

dirStr = '/home/camroom/Dropbox/Internship/MyCascades/Cascade1/training/positive/';

while ~feof(infid)
    inline = fgetl(infid);
    outline = [dirStr, regexprep(inline,' 1 (\d* \d* \d* \d*)',', [$1]')];
    fprintf(outfid, '%s\n', outline);
end

fclose(infid);
fclose(outfid);
```

What we've done there is to read in the code from the input file line by line, then use a regular expression to make the changes to the line, then write it out to the output file. There are probably better ways of applying the regular expression, but that was pretty quick.

Comment: Added the dynamic expression from my solution to yours - hope you don't mind :). Also, to make it faster, one could read the entire file in one go (one cell element per line), perform `regexprep` on the array, and add the path while writing to file.

Comment: @Jonas I don't mind at all, but if I'm honest that seems more complex to me than my original one. But then I'm terrible at regular expressions - perhaps you could explain what the advantage of your way is? (both for the OP and for my education)

Comment: To be honest - there is not actually an advantage. It's just a way to showcase a neat feature. No prob if you'd rather revert.

Comment: Thank you both, but only the answer from Sam Roberts worked for me. In @Jonas' answer, I get the error Undefined function or variable 'currentLine'.

Comment: Zynk - looks like @Jonas made an error in the copy and paste. Now edited to a version that both runs correctly and uses his neat dynamic expression, which I shall now learn.

Comment: Thanks to you both :)